I've can't be able to make that the new task stand in task-box as a button after close and open the browser using localStorage
I want to be able to scale a class-project using localStorage, saving the text into a button and when I refresh the browser that keep and, delete it when I want, since said button already is configured with a couple of actions, but I couldn't.
import '../Style-sheet/FormTask.css';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useLocalStorage } from './localStorage';

function FormTask(props)
    const [input, setInput] = useLocalStorage('input', '')
  
    const handleChange = e => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleShipping = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newTask = {
            id: uuidv4(), 
            text: input,
            fulfilled: false,
        };
        
        props.onSubmit(newTask);
    };

    return (
        <form 
            className='form-task'
            onSubmit={handleShipping}>
            <input 
                className='input-task'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Write a task'
                name='text'
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button className='button-task'
            onClick={() => ('')}>
                Add Task
            </button>
        </form>
    )
};

export default FormTask;

import { useState } from 'react';

export function useLocalStorage (key, initialValue) {
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
        try {
            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue
        } catch (error) {
            return initialValue
        };
    });

    const setValue = value => {
        try {
            setStoredValue(value)
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        };
    };

    return [storedValue, setValue];
};


I tried to reproduce your problem inside this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lucid-brook-mqsch2?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&from-embed=
Your problem is not using the value property inside the input:
 <form 
    className='form-task'
    onSubmit={handleShipping}>
    <input 
        className='input-task'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Write a task'
        name='text'
        onChange={handleChange}
        // add
        value={input}
    />
    <button className='button-task'
    onClick={() => ('')}>
        Add Task
    </button>
</form>

Now your input field should always have the value from the local storage, even on page refresh!

Thanks for the advice, David. However, I have tried to apply it, but it works as follows: This allows me to refresh the page instead of keeping the last task in a button to do it in the text box.
